# Show content if user_type is equal to X

Tags: php, sql, equals, show

I have a question.

How can you show content on a webpage if a user type is equal to value `admin`?

I want to show content only if the user had user_type admin.

I've this code rightnow but it isn't working correct, it shows the content to user and admin. I had this kind of code on my other website but that was 4years ago.

Any suggestions?

```
<?php 
if(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT user_type 
                            FROM users 
                            WHERE username = '$username'"), 
                0) == 'admin'); {
?>
ADMIN content
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Kind regards

Comment: This is poor quality php, not to mention you're using deprecated functions (*`mysql_*`*). Please save yourself now and look at [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [**MySQLi prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: Thank you. Do you maybe have a safer code thats works based on that?

Comment: While the code is poor, it should still work.

Comment: Why don't you put the result of the query into a variable so you can echo it, to see why it might not be working?

Comment: @Barmar it isn't working unfortunately. Can you help me? I'm not so experienced with that echo?

Comment: If it does not work, split it into 2 seperate instructions rather than running 2 function calls together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `;` after the `if`:

```
<?php if(...); {?>
             ^
```

That's putting an empty statement as the body of the `if`, and the next code block is being executed unconditionally.

Delete that `;`.

Comment: <?php 
if(mysql_result(mysql_query("
SELECT user_type FROM users 
WHERE username = '$username'"), 0) == 'admin'); {
?>
ADMIN content
<?php 
} 
?>

Doesn't work, removing the ;   ;(

Comment: It would be best to split up the function calls, so you can check the result of each step. Even better would be to switch to mysqli or PDO, as the mysql extension has been obsolete for years.